# GIF LZW decompression

Tags: c++, decode, gif, compression

**I am trying to implement a simple Gif-Reader in c++.** 

I currently stuck with decompressing the Imagedata.
If an image includes a **Clear Code** my decompression algorithm fails.

After the **Clear Code** I rebuild the **CodeTable** reset the **CodeSize** to **MinimumLzwCodeSize** + 1. 
Then I read the next code and add it to the indexstream. The problem is that after clearing, the next codes include values greater than the size of the current codetable. 
For example the sample file from wikipedia: [rotating-earth.gif](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif) has a code value of 262 but the GlobalColorTable is only 256. 
How do I handle this? 
I implemented the lzw decompression according to [gif spec.](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/lzw_image_data.asp).

here is the main code part of decompressing:

```
int prevCode = GetCode(ptr, offset, codeSize);
codeStream.push_back(prevCode);

while (true)
{
auto code = GetCode(ptr, offset, codeSize);

//
//Clear code
//
if (code == IndexClearCode)
{
    //reset codesize
    codeSize = blockA.LZWMinimumCodeSize + 1;
    currentNodeValue = pow(2, codeSize) - 1;

    //reset codeTable
    codeTable.resize(colorTable.size() + 2);

    //read next code
    prevCode = GetCode(ptr, offset, codeSize);
    codeStream.push_back(prevCode);

    continue;
}
else if (code == IndexEndOfInformationCode)
    break;


//exists in dictionary
if (codeTable.size() > code)
{
    if (prevCode >= codeTable.size())
    {
        prevCode = code;
        continue;
    }

    for (auto c : codeTable[code])
        codeStream.push_back(c);

    newEntry = codeTable[prevCode];
    newEntry.push_back(codeTable[code][0]);

    codeTable.push_back(newEntry);

    prevCode = code;

    if (codeTable.size() - 1 == currentNodeValue)
    {
        codeSize++;
        currentNodeValue = pow(2, codeSize) - 1;
    }
}
else
{
    if (prevCode >= codeTable.size())
    {
        prevCode = code;
        continue;
    }

    newEntry = codeTable[prevCode];
    newEntry.push_back(codeTable[prevCode][0]);

    for (auto c : newEntry)
        codeStream.push_back(c);

    codeTable.push_back(newEntry);

    prevCode = codeTable.size() - 1;

    if (codeTable.size() - 1 == currentNodeValue)
    {
        codeSize++;
        currentNodeValue = pow(2, codeSize) - 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you consider looking at existing C++ implementations and see why they work and yours does not?  Also, I really don't recommend calling `pow` to do powers of 2, since it will use floating point to do the calculation.

Comment: In stead of pow(2, codeSize), you can use (1 << codeSize) .

Comment: I am currently reviewing a working c# reader. Seems that I get the wrong code after clearing. I will use shifting for expo. of 2, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution.
It is called **Deferred clear code**. 
So when I check if the codeSize needs to be incremented I also need to check if the codeSize is already max(12), as it is possible to to get codes that are of the maximum Code Size. 
See [spec-gif89a.txt](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt).

```
if (codeTable.size() - 1 == currentNodeValue && codeSize < 12)
{
   codeSize++;
   currentNodeValue = (1 << codeSize) - 1;
}
```

Comment: just so its a bit more clear: when the table is full and has 4096 fields, it should continue reading 12 bit unsigned integers and should stop pushing new codes into the table untill it reads cc or eoi